# Changing a html input box into a jquery flicker

Tags: jquery, html

I have a input text box in html for user to type in quantity.

```
<input type="text" value="1" class="Quantity" data-id2="Quantity" />
```

What i would like is something which looks better for the user but to have the same effects of the above. I need there to be a data-d2=""Quantity" and class="Quantity" because they are used elsewhere. But i would like maybe a flicker so a user can click arrows to increase/decrease their Quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a spinbox input to increment/decrement numeric values in the given input. There are couple of options. Once there will be decent browser support you will be able to use native html5 [spinbox](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-number) Until then, check this spinbox jquery plugins: http://sean-o.com/jquery/increment/ or this one http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spinbox

Here's working example of a spinbox using latter plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/YxurP/1/

Comment: I dont want the user to increment/decrement via the up and down keys. What i would like is actual arrows on the screen so they can click on the up arrow to increase the number and down arrow to decrease

Comment: Then u will be ok with this plugin I already linked: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spinbox. Check updated answer for working example.